# Acceder dinamicante a recursos según string

Tags: c#, pdf

Tengo una lista de PDFs guardados como recursos de mi proyecto y cada pdf es un manual de rol distinto.

El proyecto tiene un ToolStrip "Manuales" el cual relleno dinámicamente con los nombres de cada PDF.

[image: ToolStrip]

Se el nombre del PDF que quiero abrir, pero lo que no se es como llegar a ese PDF de forma dinámica según un string.

[image: Código]

Básicamente necesito una especie de:

`foreach (recurso r in Resources)`

```
If(r.nombre == sender.tostring())
     byte[] PDF = r;
```

Soy autodidacta y desconozco muchísimas cosas, así que supongo que habrá formas mejores de hacer esto, en cuyo caso me gustaría conocerlas, sobre todo porque este método ralentiza muchísimo la compilación del proyecto y aun tendría que añadir como 70 manuales más.

Comment: Haber, lo que no te sabes es la ruta de donde se encuentra el pdf ej c:\Libros\carpeta\otros?

Comment: Es que los pdf son recursos del programa, no los recojo de una carpeta específica.
Quiero que cada instalación del programa los lleve incluidos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He llegado a una solución que me funciona:

```
        byte[] PDF = (byte[])Properties.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject(sender.ToString(), Properties.Resources.Culture);
```

Gracias a esta línea de código puedo recuperar un resource sabiendo su nombre y guardarlo como array de bytes, para luego ejecutarlo.

Answer (score 0):

Para abrir un pdf debes poner esto:

```
Process.Start(rutaPdf);
```

Ahora bien suponiendo que tus pdf estén guardados en la misma carpeta donde está tu ejecutable podrías hacer lo siguiente

```
string rutaPdf =   Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, "fichero.pdf");

Process.Start(rutaPdf);
```

**Application.StartupPath** devuelve la ruta en donde se encuentra el ejecutable de tu proyecto.

**Path.Combine** digamos que concatena la ruta donde se encuentra tu aplicación con el nombre del fichero sería:

ruta\fichero.pdf

y esta concatenación te da la ruta completa del fichero para que pueda ser abierto.

Para usar **Path.Combine**, debes añadir a los **usings**:

```
using System.IO;
```

Comment: Quizá estoy equivocado yo ¿no? pero, tengo entendido que en tiempo de ejecución los recursos del programa no tienen ruta ¿no?

Comment: Igualmente he probado con el código que me dices, y como sospechaba, la ruta que me devuelve no es la de los recursos, que bueno eso lo puedo parchear a mano (aunque tampoco me funcionó). Pero es que una vez publicado el programa e instalado en otro ordenador, esa ruta debería de funcionar aun menos según entiendo.