# C# Añadir archivos a proyecto, sin usar resources

Tags: c#, pdf, windows-installer

Necesito añadir a un proyecto una cantidad ingente de PDFs (Unos 100 PDF, alrededor de los 10 Gb), de tal forma que al publicarlo, el instalador se lleve consigo los PDF y cuando lo instale en otro pc, lo haga con dichos PDF y pueda acceder a ellos.

Lo he hecho añadiéndolos a resources, pero literalmente lo rompen, lanzando un error que dice que el proyecto no puede ser compilado porque se ha quedado sin espacio en memoria (Tengo 16 Gb de ram).

He buscado por todos lados, pero al desconocer la jerga y tecnicismos, no llego a nada. Doy por hecho que se pueden añadir los PDF sin ser como resources, y que se instalen junto al programa.
Entonces, No pido un código, tan solo conocer el nombre del método o métodos, o alguna página o dirección donde encontrar información al respecto.

Muchas gracias de antemano.

Esta pregunta deriva de una que formulé ayer. Os la adjunto por si ayuda a comprender mejor la situación.
[Acceder dinamicante a recursos según string](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/432664/acceder-dinamicante-a-recursos-seg%c3%ban-string)

Comment: Debería ser parte del Instalador quien empaquete el proyecto y los pdfs. Durante el proceso de instalación debería instalar tanto la aplicación como copiar los pdf a un directorio en particular al cual pueda acceder el sistema.

Comment: Puedes intentar [esto](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/visualstudio/deployment/how-to-include-a-data-file-in-a-clickonce-application?view=vs-2019). Tambien podrías intentar comprimir los pdf y descomprimirles en la primera ejecucion del programa. Y si la aplicación es a nivel interno, yo preferiría que esos archivos estuvieran en una carpeta compartida en la red local

Comment: @JuanCarlosGuibovich He creado el instalador y le agregué los PDF, pero al compilarlo me vuelve a decir que no tiene suficiente memoria.

Error: Could not find file 'D:\manuales\[Manual][Reinos Olvidados] Razas de Faerun.pdf' 'No hay suficientes recursos de memoria disponibles para completar esta operación.'

Tengo 16 Gb de ram, de los cuales uso solo 6, inclusive durante la compilación.
¿Entiendo que es una limitación a 2 Gb por ser un programa de 32bits?

Comment: He tratado de dividir los pdf en varios .cab, luego añado los cab al instalador y me sigue dando error de falta de memoria.

Comment: Que software de instalación utilizas? Algo más sencillo tal como dice @Pikoh es válido pero si lo necesitas en un instalador lo que podrías hacer es empaquetar los los PDF en un zip. Luego generas el instalador sin incluir los PDF y finalmente empaquetas el instalador más el empaquetado pdf en un solo archivo .zip que es el que distribuyes. Lógicamente para instalar debes instruir que desempauqeten y ejecuten el setyo. El script de instalación puede desempaquetar automáticamente y copiar los PDF donde desees.

Comment: También puedes dejar el script de instalación tal cual y creas un instalar.bat  que ejecute el setup y luego descomprima los PDF en el directorio dónde el sistema  espera encontrarlos. Por lo tanto tu archivo de distribución es un empaquetado con el setup, el zip con PDF y el instalar.bat

Comment: Muchas gracias por la ayuda, al final entre vuestros dos comentarios, llegué a una solución, no la ideal, pero la abrazo jaja. Estoy usando "inno setup compiler".